# Publish_action permission only for pages and not for user timeline

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, permissions

While it is possible to ask for the publish_action permission when a user connects with our app through facebook, the dialog is asking the user permission to post on their feed as well as on any pages they have access to.

The requirements only needs the user to allow posting to certain pages and not their own timelines.

In the docs:

> Permissions
>
> A user access token with publish_actions permission can be used to publish new posts on behalf of that person.
>
> A page access token with publish_actions permission can be used to publish new posts on behalf of that page.

I was wondering if it's possible to just request publish_action permission for a particular page and not the user's timeline.

The main concern here is that we dont want the user to think we're requesting too much permission.

I found the same exact question on SO but it wasnt answered:
[Is it possible to publish action from a Facebook Page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10213409/is-it-possible-to-publish-action-from-a-facebook-page)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

After the last update from 25.03.2015 to v2.3 of the Graph API, your request is finally possible.
Now you can ask for `publish_pages` instead of `publish_actions`. This permission allows you to post to pages, but not to personal accounts.

Reference: [Permissions with Facebook Login: publish_actions](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/v2.3#reference-publish_pages)

Also, please note that currently there is a bug with this permission. See discussion here:
[open graph v2.3 publish_pages - return (#200)...](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/733304666790575/)

EDIT: It seems the bug wasn't real and discussion is closed now. 
Please note it's necessary to make an API call to v2.3. -> `https://www.facebook.com/v2.3/dialog/oauth?...`

The permissions you need are `manage_pages` and `publish_pages`.

Answer (score 0):

It´s not possible unfortunately, it´s only one permission. But users who want to authorize `publish_actions` and `manage_pages` for posting to a Page should know what they are doing anyway ;)